# Unit tests for the core jQuery libraries

Tags: jquery, unit-testing

Do they exist, and if so, where's documentions and code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are in the test directory in Git.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test

Answer (score 2):

You can make unit tests with QUnit.

http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit