# Where can I get test suits or test cases for jquery itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testcase

I want to find test suits or test cases for jquery itself.

I think jquery library has some test suit for finding bugs at each release, but I cannot find it.

Are there test cases for jquery? where can I get this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit tests for the core jQuery libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125752/unit-tests-for-the-core-jquery-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

You can find them in [the jQuery github project](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

Here's the best instructions I can find for checking out and building it from a quick search

- http://docs.jquery.com/action/render/Tips_for_jQuery_Bug_Patching

but I'd hope there's better somewhere!